# SQL Server : list calculated result in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the result goal

```
[AVAILABLE WHITE]   [AVAILABLE BLUE]    [AVAILABLE GREEN]    [TOTAL AVAILABLE]
        4                  5                    3                12
```

to list the calculated values in one row as shown.

Does anyone know how this is written correctly in Microsoft SQL Server?

This is my query, hoping that the + would concatenate each statement next to the previous one, but it did not work:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Num_Avail)  
FROM 
    Goods 
WHERE 
    Color = 'White' 

    +

SELECT 
    SUM(Num_Avail) AS [Available Blue] 
FROM 
    Goods 
WHERE 
    Color = 'Blue' 

    +

SELECT 
    SUM(Num_Avail) AS [Available Green] 
FROM 
    Goods 
WHERE 
    Color = 'Green' 

SELECT 
    SUM(Num_Avail) AS [Total Available] 
FROM 
    Goods 
WHERE 
    Color = 'Blue' OR Color ='White'
```

Here is the table source

```
Create table Goods
(
     GoodsCode int not null,
     ItemCode varchar(255),
     Num_Avail int,
     Color varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Goods(GoodsCode, ItemCode, Num_Avail, Color) 
VALUES (1, 'ABC', 5, 'Blue');

INSERT INTO Goods(GoodsCode, ItemCode, Num_Avail, Color) 
VALUES (2, 'ABC', 2, 'White'); 

INSERT INTO Goods(GoodsCode, ItemCode, Num_Avail, Color)    
VALUES (3, 'DEF', 2, 'White');

INSERT INTO Goods(GoodsCode, ItemCode, Num_Avail, Color) 
VALUES (4, 'DEF', 3, 'Green');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional aggregation should do the trick

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'White' THEN Num_Avail ELSE 0 END) AS [AVAILABLE WHITE],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'Blue' THEN Num_Avail ELSE 0 END) AS [AVAILABLE BLUE],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'Green' THEN Num_Avail ELSE 0 END) AS [AVAILABLE GREEN],
    SUM(Num_Avail) AS [AVAILABLE TOTAL]
FROM 
    Goods
```

Comment: THank you @Mihal. The CONDITIONAL AGGREGATION worked exactly as I was hoping it would. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2):

simply:

```
SELECT 
    (select SUM(Num_Avail) FROM Goods WHERE Color = 'White' ) AS [AVAILABLE WHITE] , 
    (SELECT SUM(Num_Avail) FROM Goods WHERE Color = 'Blue' )   AS  [AVAILABL EBLUE] ,
    (SELECT SUM(Num_Avail) FROM Goods WHERE Color = 'Green' )  AS [Available GREEN] , 
    (SELECT SUM(Num_Avail) FROM Goods ) as  [TOTAL AVAILABLE]
```

Comment: This script is slightly more streamlined than the first one. Quite efficient. You have shown me another way to create the same result. Thanks @Ahmed Abdelqader

Comment: Just did. Tried earlier on, but did not have enough Rep. Now its good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. It is a SQL Pivot. You do not want this as your final solution because it is not dynamic. If a new color pops up it will be missed.

```
SELECT Blue, White, Green
FROM
(SELECT Color, Num_avail
    FROM goods) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
SUM(Num_Avail)
FOR Color IN (Blue, White, Green)
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: I like the Conditional aggregation. At east when you have to add into it, it will be easier to fix

Comment: and your create table query needs another ")" at the end :)

Comment: Thanks for the script. I am aware of the pivot function. However, the objective was to lay out this particular aggregated result in one row (as shown).